# Render HTML to TIFF

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, tiff

I'm working on an application where the requirements call for the app to produce a TIFF image of an HTML document for storage in a document management system.  I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 and am curious if anyone else has run into similar requirements, and if so, how did you address?

Thanks!

Comment: looks like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53956/html-to-image-tiff-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular solution wasn't suggested in [@Select0r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/255905/select0r)'s comment above and I believe it's worth mentioning.

I recently ran into [this library on CodePlex](http://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/Wikipage?ProjectName=htmlrenderer). It's written completely in managed code without and dependencies and provides `HtmlRenderer.Render()` function which renders to a `Graphics` object.

You can use it to render some HTML onto a `Bitmap` and save it as a TIFF image.

However, this library still isn't perfect and only supports simple layouts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm going to go with a similar (but not free) solution called HTMLSnap (http://www.guangmingsoft.net/htmlsnapshot/help.htm).  I ran some tests with the demo version and it seems to do the job.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This article can be help fully to you.

http://www.converthtmltoimage.com/Convert-html-to-tiff-in-vb.net.html

Following sample code shows you how to render html to image (JPG, PNG, TIF, GIF and BMP)

```
Dim _Obj As New WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot
Dim _Result As WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot.Result
With _Obj
_Result = .CaptureWebpage("http://www.WebsitesScreenshot.com")
If _Result = WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot. _
            Result.Captured Then
    .ImageFormat = WebsitesScreenshot. _
            WebsitesScreenshot.ImageFormats.TIF
    .SaveImage("c:\test.tif")
End If
End With
_Obj.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate idea: It may be posible to use word automation to save an html document to a PS or PDF printer driver, then convert it to a tiff from there. It may also be useful having a PDF within the document storage system.

Comment: The app I'm developing is a web app and most of what I've read about using Word automation on a web server (even according to Microsoft) is pretty unfavorable.  Thanks for the alternate idea though!