# Making Tiff image inside Windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, tiff

I have a Windows Service and I need to create a tiff image form a XML + XSL.

I found a way to make a tiff but this works with a web browser and DrawToBitmap.
But this is not possible inside a Windows Service because it is not possible to use a web browser class inside a Windows service.

Is there a why to do make a tiff image form a XML with C#?

Comment: It is not so clear... I think you have to use System.Drawing to create the image. Whats wrong with it in a Windows Service?

Comment: I have Edit my question. i hope i made it more clear. Sorry for by bad english

Comment: I need to understand what yuo have as input! An xml ok... but can you post it with image information ? Can you be more specific about the tiff output image? What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: the XML + XSL that the Windows service needs to transform is dynamic. So i don't have specific for it. the only thing i now for sure is that thy belong together. So i can make a HTMl of it with XslCompiledTransform. And what i need to do with the image is save  the Data that the XSL displays nothing more.

Comment: So you have to generate an image of the html that comes from this transformation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you have to do with the image but to create an image on the fly in a windows service:

Add reference to System.Drawing

try this way:

```
using System.Drawing;

namespace WindowsService1
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(100,100);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);


        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**update**

You are in a right direction using `web browser and DrawToBitmap`! To use WebBrowser you need to include `using System.Windows.Forms;` and you have to add reference at System.Windows.Forms

this is an example:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/html2image.aspx

**update**

You can also look here:

[HTML to Image .tiff File](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53956/735864)

or here:

[Render HTML to TIFF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5249002/735864)

**update**

I've found this one:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETSaveWebpageToImage-5299048d

Comment: I need to save this image.
But this will not work because i have a dynamic XML and XSL file. And I don't now how big the image needs to be